# Excel nested IF function on a range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a range of cells (i.e I have a list of "attendees" in range A2:A9) and if two particular people(say "Tom" and "John") are present in that range, I want to return the value of a another particular cell(say B1 containing "Tom-John"). 
Is there a way I can do this? 
Many thanks

Comment: Can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53796522/edit) your question with the formula(s) you have tried so far? Perhaps also a snapshot of some sample data - it would make your question just a little clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Pick a cell and enter:

```
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(MATCH("Tom",A1:A9,0)),ISNUMBER(MATCH("John",A1:A9,0))),B1,"")
```

[image]